# Problem in packing frames with tkinter in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have 2 classes for 2 different windows. In the main window, on clicking a button, the second window opens.

A frame that I'm trying to pack on the second window displays on the first main window.

The LABEL2 and Init button (class campaigns) appear in the mainwindow while all other buttons appear on the new campaigns window. How can I fix this?

Also, is the good alright in terms of best GUI programming practice?

Following is the code

```
class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        HEIGHT = 500
        WIDTH = 600
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, height = HEIGHT, width = WIDTH)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.FRAME = tk.Frame(self.master, bd = 5).place(relwidth=1, relheight =0.5, relx = 0, rely=0)
        self.LABEL = tk.Label(self.FRAME, text="Keravalon BizDev").place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 0.05, relx=0,rely=0)

        # Code to add widgets will go here...


        self.B = tk.Button(self.FRAME, text ="Campaigns", command = lambda: self.campaign_win())
        self.C = tk.Button(self.FRAME, text ="Analysis", command = self.helloCallBack)

        self.B.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.1, anchor = 'n')
        self.C.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.15, anchor = 'n')

    def helloCallBack(self):
        messagebox.showinfo( "Hello Python", "Hello World")

    def campaign_win(self):
        root_camp = tk.Tk()
        app2 = campaigns(root_camp)
        root_camp.mainloop()

class campaigns(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        super(campaigns, self).__init__()
        self.FRAME2 = tk.Frame(self.master, width=100, height =50).place(x=700,y=0)
        self.LABEL2 = tk.Label(self.FRAME2, text="Campaigns").pack()

        # Code to add widgets will go here...


        self.Init = tk.Button(self.FRAME2, text ="Initialize", command = self.helloCallBack)
        self.Skr = tk.Button(master, text ="Update Skrapp", command = self.helloCallBack)
        self.Hub = tk.Button(master, text ="Update HubSpot", command = self.helloCallBack)
        self.Wood = tk.Button(master, text ="Update Woodpecker", command = self.helloCallBack)
        self.Ex_NB = tk.Button(master, text ="Export for NeverBounce", command = self.helloCallBack)
        self.NB = tk.Button(master, text ="Update NeverBounce", command = self.helloCallBack)
        self.Ex_WP = tk.Button(master, text ="Export for Woodpecekr", command = self.helloCallBack)

        self.Init.pack()
        self.Skr.pack()
        self.Hub.pack()
        self.Wood.pack()
        self.Ex_NB.pack()
        self.NB.pack()
        self.Ex_WP.pack()    

    def helloCallBack(self):
        messagebox.showinfo( "Hello Python", "Hello World")
```

Comment: examine `self.FRAME2` and see if it is what you think it is (hint: it's not)

Comment: Hi, I removed the width and height from the frame, and placed it in a separate line. Still doesn't seem to work.